# vba - access the bytes in a numeric type

Tags: vba

```
Dim TXMessage(7) As Byte
Dim data As Long
```

How do I assign the individual bytes of `data` to `TXMessage`?

Comment: There's a couple of functions in [this article](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1052) that you might find useful.

Comment: using `CopyMemory` api `CopyMemory TXMessage(0), ByVal VarPtr(data), Len(data)`